# Can I poll for events using SDL2 on macOS outside of main thread?

Tags: c++, c, macos, sdl-2

I'm playing around with SLD2 and I've got a somewhat working game. It works great on Linux/Windows, but I'm getting an exception on macOS.

I've done input handling in a separate thread, basically it just polls for user input and then does calculations/moves sprites around etc. My problem is that on macOS it seems that the library is compiled in a way that when you call `SDL_PollEvent`, `SDL_WaitEvent` or `SDL_HasEvents` it calls `SDL_PumpEvents` from within itself, which can only be called from the main thread.

Is there a way to get the events without the functions calling `SDL_PumpEvents`? (I call that in main thread on every iteration, so it really isn't needed)

Comment: Check https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PeepEvents